# Create Depth Pass Based on Real World Units

Tags: scripting, camera, color, compositing-nodes, depth-map

I'm trying to generate synthetic training data as part of some research for my university. This data should resemble depth images captured from my camera (Realsense L515). I've been able to get good results by running the depth pass through a ColorRamp node.
[image: Node Setup]
[image]
However, rather than gradually tweak the color ramp, **I was wondering if there is a way to directly tie the real-world units to the depth color/information?** Such that the minimum distance that the camera can detect (.25 meters) is deep blue and the maximum distance (9 meters) is red as shown in the "ground truth" camera feed below.
[image]

I really appreciate any suggestions on how I can leverage the compositing nodes to mimic the camera feed as close as possible.

Comment: Map range node-- remap depth from 0.25, 9 to 0,1.  Instead of dividing by the arbitrary 7.2.  But you can do this in materials instead of compositing, via a camera data/view distance node, which is preferable for performance and preview.  You'll almost certainly want to disable color management (no display device, standard view transform) or else render to a non-color format like .exr.  The actual mapping of depth to color is not guaranteed to be along the lines of hue, it depends on your camera.  Notice the discontinuity in the foreground arm, as well as background blue.